# Path of free electrons in a metallic conductor under applied electric field

Tags: electric-current

What is the path followed by free electrons in a conductor under applied electric field? Is it a zig-zag path (due to collisions with atoms of the metal) or a curved path? Why (in each case)?

Comment: The true answer is quantum mechanical in nature and cannot even be estimated by classical physics. If you do physics at universities, basically the whole subject is organised towards teaching this to you, not just because it is important, but that it is a totally different way to understand the world around you, and nobody else can properly handle this.

Comment: I am not aware that anybody has ever measured "the path of an electron" inside a metal, so if you define science as the rational explanation of observations, then this is, at least so far, not even a scientific question. As naturallyconsistent has pointed out correctly, microscopic conduction mechanisms in metals are not a problem that can really be understood with classical physics. You can ask the question how a classical charge distribution (many electrons) behaves on a metal surface under external fields. That is a well defined problem and it is being answered by Maxwell's equations.